# Where should be post on? Stack Overflow or Web Applications?

Tags: discussion, support

I had some problems about web-design. **Not all** problems were about a bug; some problems were about web-design concepts.

Where should the questions be posted on, Stack Overflow, Web Application, or another site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DocType.](http://doctype.com/)

> Doctype is a free question and answer site for web designers. You can get fast solutions to your CSS, HTML, web design and email design problems.

Comment: This is not a stackexchange network forum

Answer (score 9):

[Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) for programming.
[Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) for website operation.
[User Interface](http://ui.stackexchange.com) for design concepts.

Do not post these questions on Web Apps, which is only for existing web applications, such as Gmail, Facebook, etc.